# Proxy doesn't add in hosts with auto-registration rule

Tags: zabbix

I installed zabbix proxy, do configuration and I added in the zabbix frontend.
I defined a auto-registration rule to add host where the label contains the proxy name, and metada added in the zabbix_agentd.conf.

But when i check hosts in the frontend , I can't see the proxy machine, I don't understand why the add isn't work.

Somebody has solution ?

Thanks

Comment: the proxy should be monitored by itself, and probably this doesn't work with auto registration

Comment: Are you looking for a host set to be auto registered. Or looking to auto register the proxy itself?